# How can I use active directory for authentication in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I use Microsoft's active directory as authentication in laravel?

Comment: try to search for LDAP functions of php

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use LDAP protocol to connect with Microsoft active directory. After configuring ldap on your active directory, you may try this extension https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel.
You can find detailed information here https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php.

Also your application server should support ldap protocol. So you need to install openldap in your docker or server.